# sicky header dosen't work after clicking slidebar js

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I'm using wordpress 3.9 , [Sticky.js](http://www.stickyjs.com) and Slidebarsjs. Two plugin works well but when I click slidebar after that sticky header stop working

[live demo here](http://www.bloodmyst.com)

```
    //Sticky header
            jQuery(function($){
                        $("#header").sticky({
                            topSpacing : -30
                        });
                });

  //Slidebar

    (function($) {
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $.slidebars();
            });
        }) (jQuery);

    //Html click
            <li class="sb-toggle-left"><h1 style="color : red">Left Slidebar</h1></li>
```

If you need more details let me know

Comment: ok i added jquery codes

Comment: add the code which runs when clicking on left slider link.

Comment: added , if u need to see slidebar website please check here [slidebar](http://plugins.adchsm.me/slidebars/)

Comment: i don't know jquery but it works if we can do instant refresh with jquery

Comment: demo link broken, please repost